Using a variable in dynamic query in SQL Databricks warehouse
I have created two widget in sql warehouse databricks.

I am able to use these variable in sql notebook like this:

I want to run below query, but I need to use club and environment variable instead of doing hardcoding it.
%sql
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_key BIGINT,
    first_name STRING,
    last_name STRING,
    is_active INT,
    source STRING
)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (is_active, source)
LOCATION "abfss://adcuat@proemdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/adc_dw/customer"

Till now this what I tried:
Approach 1:

Approach 2:


But nothing work. Can you someone please help me here.

To use the widget values for the club and environment variables in your SQL query, try the following approach:
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_key BIGINT,
    first_name STRING,
    last_name STRING,
    is_active INT,
    source STRING
)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (is_active, source)
LOCATION "abfss://folder02@dilipadbstg.dfs.core.windows.net/adc_dw/customer_{widget.club}_{widget.environment}"

In the above code, use the widget values in your SQL query by enclosing them in braces {} and prefixing with widget.
Using Python:
dbutils.widgets.text("club", "adc", "Club")
dbutils.widgets.text("environment", "uat", "Environment")
club = dbutils.widgets.get("club")
environment = dbutils.widgets.get("environment")
location = f"abfss://folder02@dilipadbstg.dfs.core.windows.net/{club}_dw/customer_{club}_{environment}"
spark.sql(f"""
CREATE TABLE customer02 (
    customer_key BIGINT,
    first_name STRING,
    last_name STRING,
    is_active INT,
    source STRING
)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (is_active, source)
LOCATION "{location}"
""")

The above code retrieves the widget values and then dynamically constructs the LOCATION string using f-strings.
Results:
club_value = dbutils.widgets.get("club") environment_value = dbutils.widgets.get("environment") print("Club value:", club_value) print("Environment value:", environment_value)
Club value: adc
Environment value: uat


Thank you for the answer. But I do not want to use Python since it will require compute or job cluster. I am using only serverless sql warehouse cluster which do ot support python language, it only support SQL language

Ok great to hear that. Hope the SQL statement that I gave helped you.

select {widget.club};  -- giving error - [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '.'. SQLSTATE: 42601 (line 1, pos 14)
== SQL ==
select {widget.club}
--------------^^^

Let me check at my end and update the solution
